# CSS. Как полностью ограничить объект в ширине

Tags: html, css, блок

Внутри блока 2 блока, первый слева, второй справа, несмотря на то что первый ограничен в ширине а правый прикреплён к правой части блока, первый смещает второй вниз, так что тот выходит за родительский блок. Как грамотно расположить их? Код прилагается:

```html
<div style="width: 200px; height: 300px; background: black;">
    <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: white;"></div>
    <div style="width: 50px; height: 300px; background: blue; float: right;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Способов полно.
Как минимум `min-width:=*`, `width: 100%`, `max-width:=*` или:

```css
.main{
    width: 326px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
}
    
.main > div {
    width: 49.95%;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
    display: inline-block;
}
    
.main > div + div{
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <div ></div>
    <div ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Дело в способе отображения элементов. По умолчанию любой div отображается как блочный, т.е. он располагается относительно предыдущего ниже. А значит, что независимо от того, какую ширину и высоту вы укажете первому блоку, второй будет ниже. Значит его нужно сделать обтекаемым, добавив `display: inline-block`, например:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: black;
}

.first {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px; 
  background: white; 
  display:inline-block;
}

.second {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: blue; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Того же эффекта вы можете добиться, если добавить `float: left` первому элементу, что также сделает его обтекаемым:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: black;
}

.first {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px; 
  background: white; 
  float: left;
}

.second {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: blue; 
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Можно воспользоваться свойством `position: absolute`, благодаря которому можно расположить элемент в любой точке:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

.first {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 50px; 
  background: white; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.second {
  width: 50px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: blue; 
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Еще вы можете воспользоваться свойством `display:grid`. Благодаря ему можно разбить элемент на ячейки, в которых можно размещать дочерние элементы. Причем элемент может не ограничиваться только одной ячейкой, но и занимать несколько. В примере ниже я разбил родительский элемент на ячейки 50х50 px и расположил в них дочерние элементы согласно вашему описанию.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 300px; 
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.first {
  background: white; 
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.second {
  background: blue; 
  grid-column: 4;
  grid-row: 1 / 7
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ расположить блоки рядом друг с другом это задать родительскому блоку CSS свойство `display: flex;`.

```css
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    background: black;
}

.item-1{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: white;
}

.item-2{
    width: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item-1" ></div>
    <div class="item-2" ></div>
</div>
```